# nodejs spawn a process in real shell and kill this process

Tags: node.js, shell, spawn

I'have a process created with a spawn in nodejs with the option `shell:true` so the process starts in a real shell. So when I try to kill this process with `streamingTask.kill()` it's not working. Without the option `shell:true` everything works fine.

This is how my code looks:

```
var options = {shell:true};  
streamingTask = spawn('gst-launch-1.0',args,options);

... 

streamingTask.kill()
```

So how can I kill this process now?

Comment: Wouldn't `streamingTask.exit(1);` do the trick?

Comment: nope the process is still running

Comment: Maybe you need to end it first. Try this: `setTimeout(function() {  streamingTask.end(); StreamingTask.close(); }, 2000);`

Comment: nope streamingTask.end() and .close are also not stopping the process

Comment: the pause and kill method also didn't worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't work because you are killing the shell process itself, not the child process(es) spawned by the shell (`gst-launch-1.0` in your case).

There's a package on npm called [tree-kill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-kill) that provides an easy one-line solution:

```
var kill = require('tree-kill');
kill(streamingTask.pid);
```

Comment: Why is this so complicated? Shouldnt this be the default behavior>

Comment: `kill(process.pid)` does not work for me, it keeps the tree after the shell. But this comment solved it for me. I do `kill(spawnedprocess.pid)`.